# Measure the hardware performance for executing a particular line of code

Tags: python, hardware, cpu-usage

In Python, I would like to know the hardware performance for executing a particular line of code. What's your preferred way of getting the hardware performance such as CPU load and memory usage?

Comment: 1/ Using Python and wondering for *hardware performance* is close to asking what is the speed of plane wheels at mach 1. 2/ If you want to know the time spend for executing a Python instruction on a specific system, `timeit` is what you want. 3/ If you want to identify bottlenecks in a script, you should *profile* it.

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/psutil/ is the library that you want

> psutil (process and system utilities) is a cross-platform library for retrieving information on running processes and system utilization (CPU, memory, disks, network, sensors) in Python. It is useful mainly for system monitoring, profiling and limiting process resources and management of running processes. It implements many functionalities offered by classic UNIX command line tools such as ps, top, iotop, lsof, netstat, ifconfig, free and others. psutil currently supports the following platforms: